# Complexity comparison of an adder and a multiplier

Tags: fpga, analysis, adder, algorithm, multiplier

I have two algorithms with different requirements of addition and multiplication operations as follows:

1. Algorithm 1: 100 additions 200 multiplications, total = 300 operations.
2. Algorithm 2: 300 additions 50 multiplications, total = 350 operations.

Algorithm 1 requires least number of operations, but most of them are multiplications which according to my basic understanding, is more complex operation than the addition in terms of hardware implementation (FPGAs, ASICs, DSPs). Algorithm 2, however, requires 400 operations, but requires less multiplications. My questions are as follows:

1. Is algorithm 2 better than algorithm 1, given this information.
2. If algorithm 2 is better, is there a systematic way to establish this result. One method in my mind was to give weights to multiplication and addition, e.g., w_addition = 1 and w_multiplication = 2 and then calculate the total number of operations, but I am not sure if this is the regular practice in algorithm design field. If there is a systematic way of doing this, can you please give me some references to quote in a paper.

Comment: Depends on how your logic units can be arranged; it is possible to do fast multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time required to perform additions and multiplications varies with the amount of circuitry one devotes to them; conversely, the amount of hardware varies according to the required speed.  If you're trying to figure out which algorithm would require more hardware to implement at some minimum acceptable speed, or which algorithm could be made to run faster with a given amount of hardware, you'll need to define your constraints.  In general, multiplies can be performed almost as fast as additions, but the hardware required to perform multiplications at the maximum possible speed is much more expensive than the hardware required to perform them more slowly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the answer in both the regimes: area limited and speed limited ? Since, I am into algorithm design, I want to find the possible application of the new algorithm and want to justify it. Can you hint on in what constraints Algorithm 2 would be more beneficial?

Comment: @ubaabd: Hardware for fast multiplication is much more expensive than hardware for fast addition.  If performing 200 multiplies at an acceptable speed would require a "full-size" multiplier, cutting the number of multiplies by 75% could probably shave 50-70% off that hardware requirement.  If the time available for each operation was sufficiently generous that even a simple multiplier would suffice, hardware costs could probably minimized by picking whichever algorithm could be sequenced most easily.